# Getting Failed to perform fetch Error while doing Maven Clean build in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am getting error as "Failed to perform fetch" while doing maven clean install. While same thing is working in Intellij of other people. i have checked the Maven settings.xml and other configuration, it's same as other teammates but unable to figure out the root cause.Also, I am able to log into my Bitbucket account. Following is the stack trace while getting the build error:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https:SomeBitbucketURL/project.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call (FetchCommand.java:254)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.JGitProvider.fetch (JGitProvider.java:352)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.JGitProvider.getAheadBehind (JGitProvider.java:339)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.lambda$loadGitData$17 (GitDataProvider.java:174)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.lambda$memoize$23 (GitDataProvider.java:272)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.lambda$loadGitData$18 (GitDataProvider.java:175)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.maybePut (GitDataProvider.java:255)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.loadGitData (GitDataProvider.java:175)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitCommitIdMojo.loadGitDataWithJGit (GitCommitIdMojo.java:604)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitCommitIdMojo.loadGitData (GitCommitIdMojo.java:563)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitCommitIdMojo.execute (GitCommitIdMojo.java:458)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https:SomeBitbucketURL/project.git: Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect (TransportHttp.java:537)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch (TransportHttp.java:362)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp (FetchProcess.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute (FetchProcess.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch (Transport.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call (FetchCommand.java:243)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.JGitProvider.fetch (JGitProvider.java:352)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.JGitProvider.getAheadBehind (JGitProvider.java:339)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.lambda$loadGitData$17 (GitDataProvider.java:174)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.lambda$memoize$23 (GitDataProvider.java:272)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.lambda$loadGitData$18 (GitDataProvider.java:175)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.maybePut (GitDataProvider.java:255)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitDataProvider.loadGitData (GitDataProvider.java:175)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitCommitIdMojo.loadGitDataWithJGit (GitCommitIdMojo.java:604)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitCommitIdMojo.loadGitData (GitCommitIdMojo.java:563)
    at pl.project13.maven.git.GitCommitIdMojo.execute (GitCommitIdMojo.java:458)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

Comment: Looks like a known bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144801

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can find the workaround through : https://github.com/git-commit-id/git-commit-id-maven-plugin/issues/421

With 3.0.0 we got two new properties (git.local.branch.ahead / git.local.branch.behind) that pretty much are only correct when using a git pull prior. This git pull might cause such transport exceptions (and requires internet).

With the 3.0.1 there will be a more clear offline option. The real fix would be that we have the plugin work in offline mode unless specified. When a user operates in offline mode and consumes the mentioned options this plugin would generate a warning.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <offline>true</offline>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

or another way

```
<configuration>
    <excludeProperties>
      <excludeProperty>^git.local.branch.*$</excludeProperty>
    </excludeProperties>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

To update the answer from @Paul-Li, this bug has been fixed but the maven dependency has changed from `pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin` (any version starting from `3.0.0`) to `io.github.git-commit-id:git-commit-id-maven-plugin:5.0.0`. No need to use the offline mode anymore.

In `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.6.3` (the latest so far), we can still find `pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin` in the plugin management. To make it work on my projects having `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent, I copied from the parent the `<executions>` and `<configuration>` like that:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>io.github.git-commit-id</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${git-commit-id-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</dateFormat>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                    <generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are pulling artifacts from private artifactory. You need to provide the artifactory username and password.

Or if you are using jgitflow-maven-plugin then something like this is needed

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <username>${git.user}</username>
        <password>${git.password}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks @abhinaba-chakraborty. checked username and password and we are not using jgitflow-maven-plugin

Comment: @implosivesilence Did configuring  the private repository in settings.xml with correct credentials work?

Comment: Yeah, cross checked that. same is working on other machine.